# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WindowsPath while converting .py using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

While trying to build an `.exe` using Pyinstaller, this error is thrown:

```
    133235 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'c:\\users\\jimit vaghela\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 901, in <module>
    fail_on_error=True)
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 796, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 770, in _open_file_or_url
    fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 291, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WindowsPath
134074 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'c:\\users\\jimit vaghela\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 901, in <module>
    fail_on_error=True)
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 796, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 770, in _open_file_or_url
    fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
  File "c:\users\jimit vaghela\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 291, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WindowsPath
```

I have found a solution posted on the Stackoverflow which states that there needs to be inserted a code into the `backend.py` in the Pyinstaller folder. But that does not work either.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that `matplotlib` was the issue. Excluding that in the module argument in Pyinstaller fixed it.

Like this:

`pyinstaller --exclude-module matplotlib main.py`

Comment: But what if one wants to actually include matplotlib?

Comment: At that time, matplotlib was having confliction issues with Pyinstaller, even basic crud applications weren't working with pyinstall that had anyways matplotlib involved. I am not sure what is causing the error here.

Comment: @WouterLievens Maybe you could downgrade your matplotlib version, that kinda helped one user out in the past when I was searching for the solutions.

Comment: @WouterLievens, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

That is currently an issue with `matplotlib`.

I solved it by editing the source file. If you don't want to edit source file, it is said that lower versions of `matplotlib` like `3.0.3` can be installed to forgo this issue.

I my case it didn't work. Anyways, below are the steps I took.

First open Python interpreter & copy the path which you get as output.

```py
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_data_path() # copy the below path
'C:\\<Python Path>\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\mpl-data'
```

Next, open file `C:\<Python Path>\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-matplotlib.py`. Just to be on safe side make a back-up of this file if you need

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import exec_statement

# old line; delete this
mpl_data_dir = exec_statement(
    "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_data_path())")

# Add this line
mpl_data_dir = 'C:\\<Python Path>\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\mpl-data'

assert mpl_data_dir, "Failed to determine matplotlib's data directory!"

datas = [
    (mpl_data_dir, "matplotlib/mpl-data"),
]
```

And don't forget to save.